# Airflow execution_date wrong value

Tags: python, apache-spark, airflow, scheduler, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have to run spark job and in that spark job we have to pass date as an argument to read current directory. I am using Airflow to schedule job. Below are some info

start_date

```
import pendulum
local_tz = pendulum.timezone("Asia/Kolkata")
start_date': datetime(year=2020, month=8, day=3,tzinfo=local_tz)
```

schedule_interval

```
schedule_interval='20 0 * * *'
```

value to pass in job

```
{{ (execution_date + macros.timedelta(hours=5,minutes=30) - macros.timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y/%m/%d") }}
```

We have to run this job at midnight for the previous day but this expression giving me date for a day before yesterday. I added 5:30 because our airflow use UTC time.

Can anybody explain what is happening here with reference?

Thanks

Comment: I think spark doesn't care about the timezone.

Comment: this time is for schedule_interval. If I am not changing timezone then job is trigger UTC midnight instead of my local midnight and till that time my data directory is not ready to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the definition for execution date

```
The execution time in Airflow is not the actual run time, but rather the start timestamp of its schedule period. For example, the execution time of the first DAG run is 2019–12–05 7:00:00, though it is executed on 2019–12–06.Dec 9, 2019
```

taken from [https://towardsdatascience.com/apache-airflow-tips-and-best-practices-ff64ce92ef8#:~:text=The%20execution%20time%20in%20Airflow,on%202019%E2%80%9312%E2%80%9306](https://towardsdatascience.com/apache-airflow-tips-and-best-practices-ff64ce92ef8#:%7E:text=The%20execution%20time%20in%20Airflow,on%202019%E2%80%9312%E2%80%9306).

You don't need the macros.timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y/%m/%d") in your value

Comment: I have removed the above value as you mentioned but even now exectution_date is pointing to 2 days ago. How to reset its value so that it points to a day before??

Comment: what is the timezone of the server where airflow runs(I am assuming UTC) ? what is the start_date. Can you please just give this start_date=datetime.datetime(2020, 08, 21),
    schedule_interval='0 0 * * *' and remove execution_date